# How can I make an object made of multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop

Here is my script which works as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function toggleForever() {
    $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow", toggleForever);
  }
  
  $("button#start").click(function () {
    toggleForever();
  });
  
  $("button#stop").click(function () {
    $("#div1").stop().animate({opacity:1}, "slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Click to fade in/out box</button>
<button id="stop">Click to stop</button><br /><br /><br />
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

Now I need to improve my code structure. In reality, I need to use `toggleForever()` function for multiple different elements. So I think if I put this line:

```
$("#div1").stop().animate({opacity:1}, "slow");
```

into the function, and passing an element like `$("#div1")` to the function, it will be more flexible. And then I can *start / stop* blinking for every element that I'm passing. Doing that is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use parameters and exactly the right course of action. Just do it.

Comment: @Bergi Well I did it .. I put the `.stop()` part into the function. But I don't know how should I use it and stop blinking.

Comment: Can you please show us that attempt? Also how many different elements are there, and how do you want to call your code upon them?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your attention .. but nevermind anymore. I'm creating two different functions like `startToggle($(this))` and `stopToggle($(this))` separately.